# Если написать GUI с помощью GPL-библиотеки - будет ли моя программа автоматом gpl и open source?

Tags: gui, лицензирование

Допустим хочу написать десктопное приложение с графическим интерфейсом НЕ open source. С закрытыми исходниками. Далее встаёт вопрос по поводу соблюдения лицензий:
Qt ныне дико платная либо под GPL и LGPLv3. GTK идёт под LGPL 2.1. JavaFX вообще под GPL v2.0 with Classpath (также не понимаю, что под этим исключением путей понимается).
Т.е. перечисленные библиотеки/фреймворки, как я это понимаю, требуют от тебя, что если твой графический интерфейс написан на них, то твой графический интерфейс (а вместе с ним выходит и вся программа) становятся open source. Прав я или нет?
При этом у LGPL есть пункт, что ты можешь применить LGPL-библиотеку к своей проприетарной программе, прилинковывая её. Но: если твоя программа буквально написана с помощью этой библиотеки, то без этой библиотеки она в принципе работать не будет и линковкой это не назовёшь.
Если всё правильно понимаю, нужно искать библиотеку для написания GUI под лицензией apache 2.0 или MIT/BSD? Или можно использовать в том числе перечисленные выше с соблюдением каких-то условий?

Comment: В случае GPL — да, будет. В случае LGPL вы рассуждаете немножко неправильно: при динамической линковке можно будет подменить библиотеку на совершенно другую, но с совместимым API/ABI — и ваша программа работать всё равно будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt стала странной последнее время, но все же. Если не хочется платить, то есть два варианта - GPL - тут да, нужно свои сорцы открывать. Но тут есть один момент. Можно сорцы не открывать "для всех", а только для Ваших пользователей, если они попросят. Но тут много тонкостей. Второй вариант - LGPL. И если отбросить все, то если использовать динамическую линковку (скопировать оригинальные dll/so от компании), то исходники Вашей программы не нужно открывать. С продажами чуточку сложнее, но тоже решаемо. Больше деталей тут https://www.quora.com/What-LGPL-license-mean-and-what-are-the-restrictions-Frameworks-like-QT-and-wxWidgets-are-lincensed-LGPL-Can-I-use-them-to-create-GUI-for-an-commercial-application

Что делать, если хочется использовать GPL,  а код открывать не хочется и иметь поменьше проблем? Вынесите весь свой важный код в отдельную библиотку (dll/so) или даже процесс и общайтесь с ним через сокет/пайп/что то свое. Готово. В этом случае, исходники UI можно выложить на сайте и скорее всего не будет никаких проблем. Более того, другие пользователи даже могут улучшать это все. Приблизительно так поступает NVidia и все ок.

---

ответ на вопрос в заголовке - да, если Ваша программа использует GPL компонент (линукется с ним), то она должна быть тоже GPL https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/resources/blog/top-10-gpl-license-questions-answered/ но она не станет автоматом такой (Вам нужно все таки указать это).